# Poisson problem with two variables...

Tags: probability

I missed this one on the test, I was wondering if anyone could help me figure it out? Thank you in advance for looking it over.

"Calls to the lost-and-found line average 12 per hour. Assume that the number of calls received in a given time period is a Poisson random variable.

a.) Find the probability that at most 5 calls are received in the next 30 minutes

b.) Find the probability that when the relief operator starts his shift, he will have to wait at least 10 minutes for the first call."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) If the rate is $12$ per hour, that is also $6$ per $30$ minutes.  So if $N$ is the random number of calls received in $30$ minutes, $N \sim {\rm Poisson}(\lambda = 6)$, and we want to find $\Pr[N \le 5]$.

b) The given rate is also equivalent to $2$ per $10$ minutes, so if $M$ is the random number of calls received in $10$ minutes, what is the distribution of $M$?  What does it mean in terms of the observed value of $M$ if the shift operator must wait more than $10$ minutes to receive his first call?  That is to say, how many calls are received in that time window?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- If the number of calls in an hour is assumed to be a Poisson random variable with mean $12$, then you should assume the  number of calls in 30 minutes is a Poisson random variable with mean $6$
- If the number of calls is assumed to be a Poisson process with rate $12$ per hour or $\frac15$ per minute, i.e. a mean of $\frac1{12}$ hours or $5$ minutes, you should consider an exponential distribution with this mean or rate.